# PyInstaller: problems on update a json file from an EXE program file (-in the next relunch, json file it's not been update)

Tags: python, json, pyinstaller

I'm testing an EXE made by pyinstaller.
In the project folder there is folder named config, which contains a json file where the user stores all the information he want about -for the GUI im using tkinter-
But finally after I restart this application and reopen the json file, it's appearing the original file.

I read about to create a new folder in execution time, where I put the origina json file. But i'm not properly satisfied with this solution.

Please any help would be appreciated

Update:

Here is the project structure:

```
/config
      |----config.json
/modules
      |----admin
      |----core
      |----graphwo
init.py
```

The code execute well, except that I want user save their info inside the config.json file in other word, in execution time. But because the PyInstaller I've used is --onefile that's not permiting to update the config.json file

Update II:

Also I have this code which gets the current path at execution time of each file -images, data and json files- the application needs:

```
def getPathFileAtExecution(relative):
    try:
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
except Exception:
    base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
return os.path.join(base_path, relative)
```

I trace any steps of the program when it's calling the json file for read and write. But after it finishes and restart againg, all changes made previously are not reflected.
May is more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

First check that you pointing into a right path. Some operating systems responds differently for some system variables and function calls.

```
import sys
import os
if getattr(sys,'frozen',False):
    current_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

config_json_file_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'config', 'config.json')
print config_json_file_path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import sys
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # we are running in a |PyInstaller| bundle
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    extDataDir = os.getcwd()
    print base_path
    print extDataDir
else:
    # we are running in a normal Python environment
    base_path = os.getcwd()
    extDataDir = os.getcwd()
```

The sys._MEIPASS variable is where your app's bundled files are run while your program is running. This is different from where your application lives. In order for your program to find and manipulate that non bundled .json file I have used `os.getcwd()` to get the folder where your application lives.

The os.getcwd() gets the current working directory that your executable is in. Then if your .json file is in a folder called `config` and that folder is in the current working directory of where your exe is run from, you would use

`ext_config = os.path.join(extDataDir, 'config', 'your.json')`